# MS Access validation rules not firing in subform

Tags: validation, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a datagrid that is a subform inside another form. I need to validate items inputted into this datagrid subform, but I'm having an excruciatingly hard time figuring out how.

Whenever I read about this on forums and on Microsoft's help site, they recommend you use Required and Validation rules on the table level. But because these are all linked tables, Access tells me these can't be saved / aren't applicable to my situation. When I save those settings, they are reset to defaults when I re-open table design view.

The other recommendation that seems to be the heaviest is to put in validation rules on the actual datagrid. Seems simple enough, but I can't get them to fire.

On my FromDate column, I put Validation Rule `Is Not Null` and Validation Text `Can't be blank`. I have also tried `Not IsNull([FromDate])` and `IsNull([FromDate])=0` but all of these had the same result of nothing happening. MS Access lets me skip over the fields, enter nothing, and continue on.

Simply put, the validation rules do not appear to be firing.

1- Should I be validating a datagrid through its datagrid property sheet validation rules?

2- If so, how do I get validation to actually fire and do the validating?

3- If I should be doing all the validiation programatically , how do I go about getting the contents of the datagrid / iterating through each new row ?

Pictures below: *left: the subform / 
right: properties of my column in the datasheet*

[image: The subform] [image]

Pictures below: *left: linked table messages saying I can't edit table properties*

[image]

Comment: Can't you open the database which contains the source table which the link points to and set Required=Yes for the FromDate field?

Comment: @HansUp I could but I inherited this project which is hooked up to other projects and would be a disaster.

Comment: Your second paragraph confused me.  So the deal is not really that you're unable to change Required for the source field; you actually don't want to.  Do I have that right now?

Comment: @HansUp I'm unable to because the table is a Linked Table - it's linked to a MSSQL database. I can do whatever I want to with this Access project, but I can't with the MSSQL database, as it will affect other projects.

Comment: I think you need to clarify exactly what you want.  Your text box Validation Rule should prevent the user from deleting the stored *FromDate* value from an existing record.  Does it work like that (yes or no, please)?  If yes, what else do you want?  If no ... I can't help you unless you share a copy of your database.

Comment: @HansUp - Yes, it prevents the user from deleting the stored *FromDate* - but it doesn't prevent the user from entering blanks in the first place, upon entering in new rows. Maybe I'm not understanding the fundamentals of Datasheets? If there's no way to prevent the user from entering bad data in the first place, it sounds like my only option is doing validation programatically in the datasheet events.

Comment: In the form's Before Update event, you can check whether FromDate is Null, and cancel the update with a notice to the user when it is Null.  Since the data source is a link to SQL Server, you might need to do the same for Before Insert, but that shouldn't be a challenge.  Would that cover what you need?

Comment: @HansUp I'd LOVE to accept your comment as an answer. ;- ) Not only did you explain that it can't be done with the GUI but the suggestion on which event to use is golden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the form's *Before Update* event to check whether *FromDate* is Null.

When it is Null, notify the user and cancel the update (`Cancel = True`).

Keep your existing *Validation Rule* for the text box.  That will give the user immediate feedback if they attempt to delete a value from the text box (instead of deferring the notice until Access tries to save the entire record).

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strPrompt As String
    If IsNull(Me!FromDate.Value) Then
        strPrompt = "FromDate can't be blank"
        MsgBox strPrompt, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Missing Value"
        Me!FromDate.SetFocus
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Test to see whether you also need the same strategy at the form's *Before Insert* event.  If you do, move that code to a separate procedure and call it from both *Before Insert* and *Before Update*.

Comment: Thank you for Cancel as well, that saved me a lot of confusion.